# How to sort view model items in razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm looping through `Model.Images` and displaying a thumbnail gallery. I want the "main" image to always display first on the page. The "main" image is a flag/property I'm setting in the object `Image`. It's called `IsMain` and it's a boolean. I'm not sure how I can sort it in code behind or sort it in the page in razor, so that the Image with property `IsMain` set to true is always displayed first?

here is where I'm displaying all the images.

```
<ul id="sortable">
  @foreach (var image in Model.Images) {
  <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">

    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
      @{ var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image.ImageThumbnail); var thumbSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64); var base64Modal = Convert.ToBase64String(image.Image); var imgSrcModal = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64Modal);
      var imageId = "pop" + image.YogaSpaceImageId; var imagesourceId = "imagesource" + image.YogaSpaceImageId; }
      <a class="image" id="@imageId" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <img id="@imagesourceId" src="@thumbSrc" data-imagesrc="@imgSrcModal" alt="image not found" width="203" height="136" />
      </a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a>  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </li>
  }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `Model.Images` is a `List<Image>`, then

```
images = Model.Images.OrderBy(i => i.IsMain).ToList();  // I think I got the syntax right, may have to check that.
```

should do it.

This can be done in the controller or the view, whichever is more appropriate to your architecture.

Comment: model.images is an icollection<images>

Comment: so, a collection of a collection?  or is your naming just weird?  Either way, I believe LINQ defines an `OrderBy` extension method for `ICollection<T>`.